# JQuery success callback function is not invoked in Chrome Extension's content script

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm developing a chrome extension for a website that will use content script to find out the user id in the DOM and call API to fetch data and then use content script to display the data.
But the ajax success callback does not seem to be invoked when the ajax call success.

My code is like this:

In background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, "dummy");
});
```

In content_script.js (I use jquery-3.2.1.min.js)

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, send) {
    userId = $("span.userid").data('user-id');
    url = "https://example.com/users/ + userId + /data/";
    var d;
    r = $.ajax({
            "method": "GET",
            "url": url,
            "success": function(response, status, xhr) {
                console.log('hihi');     //This doesn't appear in console
                console.log(response);   //This doesn't appear in console
                d = response;
                v = d.split('</x>')[1];
                u = JSON.parse(v);
                console.log(u);          //This doesn't appear in console
           }       
        });
    console.log(d);                // This is undefined
    console.log(r.responseText);   // This is undefined


    // The following setTimeout function shows the expected data
    setTimeout(function() {console.log(r.responseText);}, 3000);
});
```

From the code above, It seems that the success callback is not invoked, but the
setTimeout function works. I can accept that the first `console.log(r.responseText)` is undefined and `console.log(r.responseText)` in setTimeout function works, since the ajax call is asynchronous

I can get the `userId` in `content_script.js` and `sendMessage` to `background.js`, `background.js` fetches the data, then sends result back to `content_script.js` to update the DOM. It seem that most of the extensions use this way.

I just wondering why the success callback is not invoked. Is it related to the execute environment (isolated world) of content scripts? Or the success callback is actually invoke in somewhere, I just can't see it in console?

Comment: See the documentation: you need `return true` in onMessage listener to keep the channel open while asynchronous ajax is running.

Comment: Thanks. I try to add the `return true` in on Message listener, but it doesn't work. I'm not going to sendResponse back to background.js. I just use it to invoke content script so that I can get the user id and then update DOM.

Comment: Ah, then you need to add the example host in "permissions" key in manifest.json and maybe do the ajax in background script.

Comment: I already add the example host in "permissions" key in manifest.json. I can do the ajax in background script. I'm just curious why the success callback is not invoked. Thank you again.